# How to calculate datentime differences using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data stored in a sqlite db using javascript.I am trying to calculate the time difference for the stored data.I have n no of objects in that created_at and field3 is the data to be performed in this if field3 is 0 i have to ignore and if field3 is 1 we have to calculate the date n time diff from that obj date n time to the next obj where field3 end with 1. I am unable to do it.Can anyone help me how to do this???Thankyou.

```
var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status == 200) {
        successHandler && successHandler(xhr.response);
    } else {
        errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
       }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

$.getJSON("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/"+did+"/feeds.json? api_key="+apikey, function(json1) {
console.log(json1);
json1.feeds.forEach(function(feed,i){
    console.log("\n The details of " + i + "th Object are :  \nCreated_at: "    + feed.created_at + "\nField3:" + feed.field3);      
 power();
 function power(){
    if(feed.field3 == 1){       
            //Start Time
            var d1 = new Date("2017-03-14T16:35:52Z");
            console.log(d1);
            //End Time
            var d2 = new Date("2017-03-14T16:47:55Z");
            console.log(d2);
            //Time difference in milli seconds
            var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            console.log(diff);
            }else{
                console.log("Field3 is 0");
            }
       }
  }
```

I tried using the above code giving some sample dates is var d1 n d2 i got the difference correctly.But how can i do it for the n no of objs data.
The data is as follows:

```
    "feeds": [
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:32Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:42Z",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:50Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T02:44:08Z",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T02:45:51Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T14:45:36Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T14:55:38Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:05:39Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:15:40Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:25:42Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:35:43Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:45:49Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:55:46Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:05:48Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:15:49Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:25:51Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:35:52Z",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:41:54Z",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:45:58Z",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:47:55Z",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:50:10Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:55:54Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:05:57Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:15:59Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:26:00Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:36:03Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:46:05Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:56:08Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:06:09Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:16:12Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:26:13Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:36:17Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:46:20Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:56:20Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:06:21Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:16:25Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:26:26Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:36:30Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:46:34Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:56:36Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:06:38Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:16:39Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:26:47Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:36:49Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:46:50Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:56:52Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:06:56Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:16:56Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:26:56Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:36:58Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:47:04Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:57:07Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:07:10Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:17:11Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:27:19Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:37:20Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:47:22Z",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:51:14Z",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:54:43Z",
        "field3": "0"
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anusha, Please use this code, validate and let me know if it works,

```
var feeds =  [ 
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:32Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:42Z",
    "field3": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:50Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T02:44:08Z",
    "field3": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T02:45:51Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T14:45:36Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T14:55:38Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:05:39Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:15:40Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:25:42Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:35:43Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:45:49Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:55:46Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:05:48Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:15:49Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:25:51Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:35:52Z",
    "field3": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:41:54Z",
    "field3": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:45:58Z",
    "field3": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:47:55Z",
    "field3": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:50:10Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:55:54Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:05:57Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:15:59Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:26:00Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:36:03Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:46:05Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T17:56:08Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:06:09Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:16:12Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:26:13Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:36:17Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:46:20Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T18:56:20Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:06:21Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:16:25Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:26:26Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:36:30Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:46:34Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T19:56:36Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:06:38Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:16:39Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:26:47Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:36:49Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:46:50Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T20:56:52Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:06:56Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:16:56Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:26:56Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:36:58Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:47:04Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T21:57:07Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:07:10Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:17:11Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:27:19Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:37:20Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:47:22Z",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:51:14Z",
    "field3": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-03-14T22:54:43Z",
    "field3": "0"
}
]
```

Create the JSON as mentioned above and call the below function

```
function power(){
for (var i=0;i<feeds.length;i++) //feeds should contain the JSON data like mentioned above
{
        if(feeds[i]["field3"] === "1"){       
            //Start Time
            var d1 = new Date(feeds[i]["created_at"]);
            console.log(d1);
    for (var j=i+1;j<feeds.length;j++) //compare objects starting from 'i' till next "1" is found
        {   
            if(feeds[j]["field3"] === "1")  
            {
                        //End Time
                        var d2 = new Date(feeds[j]["created_at"]);
                        console.log(d2);
                j=feeds.length;
            }
        }
            //Time difference in milli seconds
        var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        console.log(diff);
        }else{
                console.log("Field3 is 0");
            }
}
```

Comment: No its not working it is taking all obj of field3 as 0 @Gowtham Shiva

Comment: Anusha, am able to run it. I get 6 differences totally. Can you share your code in a fiddle? I will take a look

Comment: It is running for me as well but the date n time values are coming wrong it is not according to the json data@Gowtham Shiva

Comment: Anusha, i have updated the for loops in the function. Please try now ..

Comment: Now also i am getting the wrong values only @ Gowtham Shiva

Comment: Send me an example with the values that you are trying(d1 and d2). i will verify and get back to you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgdy17n1/5/ check the link for the code i am trying@Gowtham Shiva

Comment: Everything in your fiddle is correct. Which value to you think its wrong? My output and your output matches

Comment: can you please send me ur output what ur getting@Gowtham Shiva

Comment: 6206000
49904000
362000
244000
117000
21799000,   you also get the same values except that those are divided by 1000.

Comment: Data and the output are not matching the values d1 and d2                  d1=Tue Mar 14 2017 06:30:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
d2=Tue Mar 14 2017 08:14:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
diff=6206 this is the 1 result in the output the d1 n d2 time stamp is not there in the feeds data.@Gowtham Shiva

Comment: That is because our browsers show only IST timings. The time stamp in the feeds + 05:30 . Thats why you see difference. But the values that we get are correct. Since you are only dealing with time difference, it will not be a problem

Comment: Ok..got it but d1=Tue Mar 14 2017 06:30:42 GMT+0530(IST) after this the next obj field3 is 0 so it has to calculate the time only up to that obj time stamp but here the d2 value is taking the next obj where we get field3=1@Gowtham Shiva

Comment: Anusha, in your question you have mentioned just to use the date if field3 is '1'. Thats why sent you this logic. If its not the case, update the corrected question and i can work on resolution for that

Comment: In the above code fun power() in that we have to change the second for loop if cond to if(feeds[j]["field3"] === "0") this solved my issue.Thank you for ur help @Gowtham Shiva

Comment: Anusha, Nice to hear. Please vote up if my answered helped you!!